# Error running skflow example

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

I just installed skflow and TensorFlow and I'm having a problem with the example that comes with skflow. The example code is:

```py
import random
import pandas
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

import tensorflow as tf
import skflow

data = pandas.read_csv('tf_examples/data/titanic_train.csv')

# Use SciKit Learn
y, X = data['Survived'], data[['Age', 'SibSp', 'Fare']].fillna(0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
print accuracy_score(lr.predict(X_test), y_test)

# 3 layer neural network with rectified linear activation.

random.seed(42)
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowDNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                            n_classes=2, batch_size=128, steps=500,
                                            learning_rate=0.05)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
print accuracy_score(classifier.predict(X_test), y_test)
```

When I run this example, I get:

```py
python Example1.py
0.664804469274
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Example1.py", line 27, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skflow/__init__.py", line 119, in fit
    self._setup_data_feeder(X, y)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skflow/__init__.py", line 71, in _setup_data_feeder
    self.n_classes, self.batch_size)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skflow/data_feeder.py", line 61, in __init__
    x_dtype = np.int64 if X.dtype == np.int64 else np.float32
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2246, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

The failure occurs on:

```py
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an issue with the interface between skflow and pandas. Try calling `.values` on the data frames before passing them to skflow:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values)
print accuracy_score(lr.predict(X_test.values), y_test.values)

# 3 layer neural network with rectified linear activation.

random.seed(42)
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowDNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                        n_classes=2, batch_size=128, steps=500,
                                        learning_rate=0.05)
classifier.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values)
print accuracy_score(classifier.predict(X_test.values), y_test.values)
```

Comment: That Works!  Thank you.

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you! I've been struggling for hours trying to make this example working.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for using skflow! We've added pandas support long time ago. You can find the specific implementation [io/pandas_io.py in skflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/blob/master/skflow/io/pandas_io.py):

More of our examples now use pandas to load the data, for example, the text classification examples, like [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/blob/master/examples/text_classification.py):

Hope this helps and happy using skflow!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11267575)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the tip. I have revised the answer.